# SqlDataSourceEnumerator doesn't returns a list of SQL Server names

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have one problem with SqlDataSourceEnumerator. Method GetDataSources() returns DataTable with no rows. And this problem happens only on one computer with OS Win 8.1 on it. Here is a problem code:

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        DataTable dataTable = instance.GetDataSources();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            Console.WriteLine($"{row[0]}  |  {row[1]}  |  {row[2]}  |  {row[3]}");
```

I think, that problem is in some windows settings maybe but which one? Does any body know what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was reinstalling of .net Freamework. Very simple decision )